# PhP $stmt->fetch() while loop keeps replacing existing data

Tags: php, oop, object

Running `$stmt->fetch()` in a `while()` loop replaces all previously collected data in an `object` with the last record, even if you push it to an array in the loop.

> I have a simple database called `dbemployee`

[image: database entries]

I've written a small script to get all the employees above a specific age.

Heres my code:

```php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$output = new stdClass();
$employee = new stdClass();
// $ageCheck = $_POST['ageCheck'];
$ageCheck = 18;
$sql = "SELECT ID, vemail, vname, vage FROM dbemployee WHERE vage > ?";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$ageCheck);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($ID, $vemail, $vname, $vage);
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $employee->ID = $ID;
            $employee->vemail = $vemail;
            $employee->vname = $vname;
            $employee->vage = $vage;
            $output->data[] = $employee;
        }
    } else {
        $output->data = "";
    }
    $output->response = "SUCCESS";
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r($output);
?>
```

Surprisingly all I'm getting is 5 entries of the last result as if the last result is replacing previous results.

[image]

Comment: Your code overwrite the `$employee` every loop. But you already did the correct approach by putting the data into an array. You can restore the result iterating the array with `foreach($output->data as $employee) { ... }`. AS you are sending a json, just use `json_encode($output->data);` and you are good to go.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I've tried that as well. It seems like some gremlin are replacing previous content in `$output->data` array even though im moving everything out in the loop by using `$output->data[] = $employee;` i've attached screenshot of `print_r($output)` in the question.

Comment: Ok I see now, check my answer

Comment: FYI, you could do it much more easily using PDO. If you are only starting with PHP, please forget about mysqli and learn PDO instead. It will be so much easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance inside the loop, otherwise it will point to the same memory address:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $employee = new stdClass;
    $employee->ID = $ID;
   ...
```

You can check this in the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> When assigning an already created instance of a class to a new variable, the new variable will access the same instance as the object that was assigned. This behaviour is the same when passing instances to a function. A copy of an already created object can be made by cloning it.

Comment: I've searched it all over the Internet. This is definitely going to help a lot of people in the future. Thank you @Felippe